# Add "type" to my custom input plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to add "type" field that i would be able to use as tag when filtering to my input plugin.
For example, I can add "type" in the 'file' input plugin, and filter it later.
Code:

```
input {

    file {

        path => "/var/log/%{type}.%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH}"

        type => "myType"
    }
}

filter {

    if [type] == "myType"

    ...

}

output {

    ...

}
```

I looked at the file input plugin implementation, and did not see any field related to the "type" field.

So i just tried to add it like this:

```
input {

myPlugin {

    path => "/var/log/%{type}.%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH}"

    type => "myType"
    }

}
```

But the filtering did not work at all.

How can i add this "tag" (or whatever it is) to my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The functionalitiy of [type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-type) is to use it for filtering:

> Types are used mainly for filter activation.

So you can't actually see a new field being created unless you have created a new field under your filter, something like this:

```
input {    
    file {    
        path => "/var/log/%{type}.%{+yyyy.MM.dd.HH}"    
        type => "myType"
    }
}

filter {    
    if [type] == "myType"{
       add_field => { 
           "somefield" => "this is a sample" <--- this will actually create the field
       }
       add_tag => "myType" <--- this would actually create a tag for your es record if it matches the filter

    }             
}
```

You could maybe check out [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field), in order to add a new field and [adding tags](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-tags) as well. **Make sure** your plugin supports `type`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid it does not :) 
For some reason, writing type=>"something" for File (Or tcp, udp and more) input is being recognized by the filtering part, even though there is no such field in the file input plugin.
But when i add, for filtering usage by type, is does not work.

Comment: How can i make sure my plugin supports 'type'?

Comment: @Itzik984 you mean, you're trying to use *type* directly within your *filter* itself?

Comment: I also tried adding the tag in my plugin without using the variable, and adding it as a part of the transferred event, still did not work

Comment: Seems like most of the **filter plugins** have the [add_tag property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-add_tag). It didn't work as well?

Comment: It wont help because i need this line:

if [type] == "myType" before starting to add_tag

Comment: I need to know which input plugin i'm flitering before i start filtering it

Comment: As per the doc, I'm afraid you can't just use it within the *filter* without assigning any value to it.

Comment: Which still leaves me very confused, how come adding "type=>myType"
to the file plugin is read and accepted by the filter, and my does not?

Comment: If your plugin inherits from `Logstash::Inputs::Base` then you get the [`type` config for free](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/logstash-core/lib/logstash/inputs/base.rb#L24-L29).